# How to stop "pop out" in embedded video with <iframe> from google drive

Tags: css, video, iframe, embed

with Google Drive you may embed videos in your website with the  tag:

```
<**iframe src="https://drive.google.com**/file/d/LINKTOMYFILE/preview"  width="640" height="480" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless></iframe>
```

on the **Top Right there is a Gray Box**. This takes you to the download / embedding GoogleDrive page. I'd like to stop that.

Anyone one knows **how to hide** it?

**Or at least how to mask it** with a customs CSS?

this is what I get by inspecting the element in the div:

```css
<div class="drive-viewer-popout-button drive-viewer-dark-button goog-inline-block drive-viewer-button" role="button" tabindex="0" data-tooltip-unhoverable="true" data-tooltip-delay="500" data-tooltip-class="drive-viewer-jfk-tooltip" data-tooltip-align="b,c" data-tooltip-offset="-6" aria-label="Pop out" data-tooltip="Pop out" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">
<div class="drive-viewer-icon drive-viewer-nav-icon">
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Thank you Thomas! Good Idea!

The following does the job for me.
The pop-out is not hidden (it hides itself after few seconds) but it stays inaccessible.
I think it is the least ugly solution.

```html
<div  style="width: 640px; height: 480px; position: relative;">

      <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/LINKTOMYFILE/preview"   width="640" height="480" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless=""></iframe>

      <div style="width: 80px; height: 80px; position: absolute; opacity: 0; right: 0px; top: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

PS
The "opacity: 0" is a workaround for Mozilla

You can also masking the pop-out button with whatever image you like using above code. Make sure the size of the masking image is 48x48 pixel and transparent background. Here is the modified version of the code.

```html
<div  style="width: 640px; height: 480px; position: relative;">
  <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MfhMdv4mw_20UWENUSt1PzmU7IQVpCXf/preview"   width="640" height="360" allow="fullscreen" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless="">
  </iframe>
  <div style="width: 48px; height: 48px; position: absolute; right: 6px; top: 6px;">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/bJNBHXp/guitar-1.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG the best answer ever

Answer (score 4):

You can't prevent it from popping out as that's something Google implemented. You also can't change the button normally as it's Google's page and you can't modify it.

You can't "reach" into the page loaded by an iframe and modify it, unless you have cross-site scripting enabled on the child page (google's page), and Google would never allow that for security reasons. If that would be able I could serve people a Google Drive page but for example modify the download button to download malware.

The only solution would be to place a div over the iframe, on top of the button. But still, it's not really pretty and usually frowned upon. Google offers the service for free so they determine how people use it.

If you run the example below, look at the red box at the top right corner.

Something like:

```css
.hidebtn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #FF0000;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hidebtn">button</div>
<iframe src="https://www.example.com" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="500"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be like this. I hope it's working.

```
<div  style="width: 640px; height: 480px; position: relative;">
      <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxLbnVHP6GWpV2ZIZEc4SkNTOTQ/preview"   width="640" height="480" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless=""></iframe>
      <div style="width: 80px; height: 80px; position: absolute; opacity: 0; right: 0px; top: 0px;"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't work. Do `tab`, `tab`, `tab` and `space` or `Enter`

Answer (score 3):

A simple option is to avoid popups using [sandbox parameter](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp) and allowing just options that need google drive to reproduce the video:

```
<iframe src="https://drive.goo..." sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts"></iframe>
```

It doesn't hide the button, but it prevents the iframe to popup a new window so the button becomes useless.

Answer (score 2):

For me the answer by u32i64/asd worked well to stop the icon being clickable. To get rid of the black bars too i changed the code to this:

```
<div class="responsive-container">

<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fy4AwZZVF-DLAenTSxQl93icdXfef/preview"    frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless=""></iframe>
<div style="width: 80px; height: 80px; position: absolute; opacity: 0; right: 0px; top: 0px;"> </div>
```

Make sure the http address ends with 'PREVIEW')

*Important* You have to add this to your 'additional CSS':

```
.responsive-container {
position:relative;
padding-bottom:56.25%;
padding-top:30px;
height:0;
overflow:hidden;
}

.responsive-container iframe, .responsive-container object, .responsive-container embed {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks s1h4d0, It worked for me, maybe in terms of programming it is not the best, but it works and I thank you.

```css
.hidebtn {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  background: #000000; /*remove this if you want to put only the logo.*/
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O71QlISu_yRvT5Q1_h3S8OHocjgpuhIx/preview" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="500"></iframe><div class="hidebtn"><img src="https://mungowarez.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/44918-O48GVC-01-2.png"></div>
```

If the above code doesn't work, add the  inside the div and then add the image, do it like this:

```css
.hidebtn {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  background: #000000; /*remove this if you want to put only the logo.*/
}
```

```html
<div class="hidebtn"><iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O71QlISu_yRvT5Q1_h3S8OHocjgpuhIx/preview" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="500"></iframe><img src="https://mungowarez.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/44918-O48GVC-01-2.png"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Change the drive.google.com in the URL to googledrive.com and some other changes:

1. Get the unique video identifier (0B6VvIWR7judDX25yUGxVNERWUj)
2. Put into this html:

```html
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
<video src="http://googledrive.com/host/0B6VvIWR7judDX25yUGxVNERWUj" controls width="100%" height="auto"></video>
</body>
```

The "body oncontectmenu" simply removes the ability to right-click anything on the screen, because without this you can right click the video and download the file.  Of course the right click ability is removed from the whole page and people can still find the file by inspecting the page source.

Answer (score 0):

```css
<div class="drive-viewer-popout-button drive-viewer-dark-button goog-inline-block drive-viewer-button" role="button" tabindex="0" data-tooltip-unhoverable="true" data-tooltip-delay="500" data-tooltip-class="drive-viewer-jfk-tooltip" data-tooltip-align="b,c" data-tooltip-offset="-6" aria-label="Pop out" data-tooltip="Pop out" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">
<div class="drive-viewer-icon drive-viewer-nav-icon">
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a more simple method of blocking the pop-out on googledrive video's and docs,
Wherever you are placing the html,inline frame or lightbox on your website page, insert a rectangular shape and place it over where you want to block the pop-out.
Next- click on the shape to get it's properties, there you should find a number of options
clear all the other options, unless you want to insert your own link or logo, make the the shape transparent, if you have the option of showing a border line I would advise keeping this to 1 setting until you have covered the position of the pop-out, once you have found the correct position, remove the border line and lock it in place. this works as I have used this method many times to block out links that appear on video's and documents, it is simple and does not require the use of any code. This method will only work if you have set the dimensions of your document or video, once you done all that test your video or document, you will find that the icon still appears but unable to click on it. you can use this method to stop the user gaining access to your information or a third party website which takes them away from your page. this method can also be used for preventing someone right clicking over your video or documents and photographs, if they try to copy it, a black box is all they will get. however,you  may still get the info from elements/source code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the previous suggestions and they did not work because "Google Drive refused to connect".

I came up with a completely different approach to solve the original problem (to avoid "download / embedding GoogleDrive page"), which is very simple:

1. Create a Google Slides presentation, insert in a slide the video you have in Google Drive.
2. Select File - Publish to the web - Embed, and copy the code that is generated.
3. In Google Sites, select Embed - Embeded code, and paste it there.

This solution provides also more options that you control in Slides for the videos, such as automatic playing, select timing of the video, etc.

Answer (score -3):

```css
<div class="drive-viewer-popout-button drive-viewer-dark-button goog-inline-block drive-viewer-button" role="button" tabindex="0" data-tooltip-unhoverable="true" data-tooltip-delay="500" data-tooltip-class="drive-viewer-jfk-tooltip" data-tooltip-align="b,c" data-tooltip-offset="-6" aria-label="Pop out" data-tooltip="Pop out" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">
<div class="drive-viewer-icon drive-viewer-nav-icon">
</div></div>
```

Mano Souza · RIO DE PEDRAS.hmtl